# Where should I meet Penelope?

Tags: knowledge, mystery

I woke up to see that my car and \$4100 cash had been stolen from me. I found this note and map on my doorstep:

> I need to get away from Richard. As you know he is possessive and controlling. I am stopping in 4 cities and I've taken exactly enough cash for one night at a hotel in each city. Meet me at the Hyatt in the 4th city and I promise I'll pay you back. - Penelope
>
> 1. Chicago, IL
> 2. Philadelphia, PA
> 3. New York, NY
> 4. (illegible)

[image]

Where should I meet her?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is all about

> Monopoly

The places Penelope is going are:

> Cities located in states whose names are streets in the Monopoly game.  (I didn't even notice until just now, but this is also hinted at by the color of the text on the supplied map—each city is in the color of its street's property color group!) So:
>  $\begin{array}{lll}\\\rm Chicago&\bf ILLINOIS~~Ave.&\text{hotel rent is \$1100}.\\\rm Philadelphia&\bf PENNSYLVANIA~~Ave.&\text{hotel rent is \$1400.}\\\rm New~York&\bf NEW~~YORK~~Ave.&\text{hotel rent is \$1000.}\end{array}$
>
>  Each of these cities is the largest city in their respective state.
>  After taking those rents from \$4100, there is \$600 left for the fourth loccation.
>  That means it must be the largest city in $\bf CONNECTICUT$, whose rent is \$600.

So you need to meet her at:

> **The Hyatt in Bridgeport, CT**.

Comment: Harrumph. The *real* monopoly uses streets in London :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor What color is the sky in your world? ;)

Comment: @Rand I knew somebody would complain about that :D

Comment: @Rubio Grey, mostly :-P

Comment: I regret to inform that there is no Hyatt in (illegible)..

Comment: @Jive I guess she didn’t really plan to pay me back!

Comment: Btw there was one more tiny clue in the names of the characters, Rich and Penny :)

Comment: There are other monopoly games then my special edition Zelda Monopoly game? :O

Comment: @Randal'Thor What do you mean by original? The Parker Brothers' [1935 patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US2026082) has the Atlantic City names on it. The [1904 patent] for the original board design doesn't have any names at all. It seems like the real version to you is the UK version which is [still for sale](https://www.hasbro.com/en-gb/product/monopoly-classic-game:7EABAF97-5056-9047-F577-8F4663C79E75) with the exact same name and product number as the Atlantic City version (change "en-gb" in the URL to "en-us"). However, that version was first released in 1936 vs 1935 for the original.

Comment: I guess we know [how she's going to pay you back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqYGC.jpg) too.

Comment: Possibly an unintended clue, but a car is one of the player pieces in some editions of Monopoly.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is

> Portland, ME

Based on

> The assumption that she'll continue heading in an east / north direction, the observation that she's only stopping in "major" cities, and the fact that Portland is the only such city (as far as I can tell) with only one Hyatt hotel.

Comment: Sorry, Hyatt was just a random hotel name, didn’t mean for that to be misleading :)

Comment: No worries! I figured I wasn't on the money, because my answer doesn't explain the specific $4100 figure.